# Why unstuck transaction is sending again and again and how to solve this problem?

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions

I started Bitcoin Core with `-zapwallettxes=1` and unconfirmed transaction came back to wallet. Next sent transaction was unconfirmed too. I repeated above action and resent transaction. It was unconfirmed again and do `-zapwallettxes=1` again. Everything is looking good but after few minutes last transaction was sent again with out do anything my self. Where I'm wrong and how to find solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running a new version of Bitcoin Core, you also have to delete `mempool.dat` when you try to remove an unconfirmed transaction, as it will be in the mempool as well.

Comment: [(An issue is already filled on Github for this unexpected behavior.)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/9710)